# how to remove \ from a word \"hello\" in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

From webservice i get the data as json but the problem is the json comes with all " with a \ ie "all" comes as \"all\"

How to make this a valid json and then a dictionary?

```
{
    GetDataResult = "[{\"www\":{\"0\":{\"ID\":\"10233\",\"Queue\":\"COMPLETED\",\"EstCommName\":\"\U062e\U0631\U0645 \U0644\U0644\U0627\U0644\U0648\U0645\U0646\U064a\U0648\U0645 \U0648\U0627\U0644\U0632\U062c\U0627\U062c\",\"ReturnTime\":\"\",\"Latitude\":\"\",\"Longitude\":\"\"},\"1\":{\"ID\":\"10304\",\"Queue\":\"COMPLETED\",\"EstCommName\":\"\U0627\U062d\U0645\U062f \U0627\U0644\U0643\U0646\U062f\U064a \U0644\U0644\U0627\U0644\U0645\U0648\U0646\U064a\U0648\U0645 \U0648\U0627\U0644\U0632\U062c\U0627\U062c\",\"ReturnTime\":\"\",\"Latitude\":\"\",\"Longitude\":\"\"},\"2\":{\"ID\":\"10667\",\"Queue\":\"FRESH\",\"EstCommName\":\"\U0645\U0646\U062c\U0631\U0629 \U0627\U0644\U062e\U0632\U0646\U0629\",\"ReturnTime\":\"\",\"Latitude\":\"\",\"Longitude\":\"\"},\"3\":{\"ID\":\"10777\",\"Queue\":\"FRESH\",\"EstCommName\":\"\U0645\U0624\U0633\U0633\U0647 \U062c\U0647\U0627\U0645 \U0644\U0627\U0639\U0645\U0627\U0644 \U0627\U0644\U0633\U064a\U0631\U0627\U0645\U064a\U0643\",\"ReturnTime\":\"\",\"Latitude\":\"\",\"Longitude\":\"\"}}},{\"asd\":{}},{\"ssd\":{}}]";
```

In other words

**TLDR**

how to remove \ from a word \"hello\".? ie output needed is "hello".

**What i tried**

```
     NSLog(@"%@",[[op objectForKey:@"GetSampleDataResult"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]);
```

Comment: You have to use `NSJSONSerialization` for `GetDataResult` also.

Comment: You are replacing " with "" try to replace \ with "".
i.e `NSLog(@"%@",[[op objectForKey:@"GetSampleDataResult"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""]);`

Comment: What is "GetDataResult" at all? A string literal? A console output? Something hand-crafted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this but something like this can work for you.

**Sample Code :**

```
NSString *yourString = [yourJSON objectForKey:@"GetDataResult"];
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *www = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"www :: %@",www);
```

Comment: thats not the way to convert a string

Comment: So the problem was not with `\"`. The problem was, that when you printed out the JSON string the _output_ contained those escapes, not the _actual_ string.

Comment: Now it looks correct, and using NSJSONSerialization is better than any string manipulation, because the strings inside the nested JSON could have escaped quotation marks or colons ...

Comment: By the way, that JSON string contains Array as the root type. You used `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @iMartin: Yeah. Thanks for correcting. I updated it to `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my head, to replace \" you need to specify it as \\\"

reason being that \ itself is used as an escape character and thus you need to escape:

- \ with \\
- " with \"

but the quotes are needed so you need to rid yourself of the \
so this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[op objectForKey:@"GetSampleDataResult"]
             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\"
             withString:@""]);
```

but as mentioned, NSJSONSerialization is the best way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

```
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];
```

Be careful with quotation marks and backslashes.

- Result of `\\\"` will be `\"`, exactly what you need to find.
- Result of `\"` will be `"`, exactly what you need to replace.

**Edit:** This is answer to *“How to remove `\` from a word `\"hello\"`?”*, not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this below:--

```
NSString *word= @"'\'hello'\'";
    NSArray *arr=[word componentsSeparatedByString:@"'\'"];
    for (NSString *str in arr)
    {
        if ([str length] >0)
        {
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        }
    }
```